# How to do a LIKE query with linq?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

How can i perform an LIKE query within Linq?

I have the following query i would like to execute.

```
var results = from c in db.costumers
              where c.FullName LIKE "%"+FirstName+"%,"+LastName
              select c;
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could use **[SqlMethods.Like(matchExpression,pattern)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx)**

```
var results = from c in db.costumers
              where SqlMethods.Like(c.FullName, "%"+FirstName+"%,"+LastName)
              select c;
```

*The use of this method outside of LINQ to SQL will always throw a NotSupportedException exception.*

Comment: I didn't have time to monkey around with this  :     where SqlMethods.Like(s.Email, id + "%")       that through an error (yes i have the using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;   ,  I changed to   where s.Email.Contains(id)    even though that is not the same, I can make it work with changing to EndsWith

Comment: For EF Core it's `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EF.Functions.Like(c.FullName, $"%{fullName}%")`.

Comment: I also thought there was something wrong with the SqlMethods.Like, but my .NET Framework just is 4.8 and needs to bee 4.8.1.

Answer (score 47):

Try using string.Contains () combined with EndsWith.

```
var results = from c in db.Customers
              where c.FullName.Contains (FirstName) && c.FullName.EndsWith (LastName)
              select c;
```

Comment: I prefer this over the SqlMethods

Comment: In contrast to a `like` query, this is not case insensitive.

Comment: This query is translated to an SQL LIKE statement if using Entity Framework, so its case sensitiveness depends on the collation of the column/table/db.

Answer (score 18):

Try like this

```
var results = db.costumers.Where(X=>X.FullName.Contains(FirstName)&&(X=>X.FullName.EndsWith(LastName))
                          .Select(X=>X);
```

Comment: Why not using the '&&' operator, instead of the double Where clause?

Comment: @max Why not 2 where clause? If each `where` clause are on its own line, it make the code more readable if there are many long conditions.

Comment: This should be the answer.  @Phil1970 Double Where would be a good choice if you have more than 3 conditions. It's my personal opinion though.

Answer (score 6):

2019 is here:

Requires EF6

```
using System.Data.Entity;
string searchStr ="bla bla bla";
var result = _dbContext.SomeTable.Where(x=> DbFunctions.Like(x.NameAr, string.Format("%{0}%", searchStr ))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: not only EF6, required EF 6.2.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.like?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

Comment: Just wanted to say that .FirstOrDefault() may be extra in this example, since you may not be wanting only 1 result.

Answer (score 5):

```
 where c.FullName.Contains("string")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String [] obj = (from c in db.Contacts
                           where c.FirstName.StartsWith(prefixText)
                           select c.FirstName).ToArray();
            return obj;
```

StartsWith() and EndsWith() can help you a lot here. If you want to find data in between the field, then Contains() can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use contains:

```
string[] example = { "sample1", "sample2" };
var result = (from c in example where c.Contains("2") select c);
// returns only sample2
```

Answer (score 0):

`var StudentList = dbContext.Students.SqlQuery("Select * from Students where Email like '%gmail%'").ToList<Student>();`

User can use this of like query in **Linq** and fill the student model.