# how to write Like Query for search Username from database in LINQ and ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, ado.net

Dear i want to search the user from database table  when user was entered the value into search textbox by using LINQ in ADO.net

i have one search textbox ..when user enter any letter than search Username from table who's name contain this letter !

i have Code for this:-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Userlist(string UserName)
    {
        var U_master = db.User_Masters.ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
            U_master = U_master.Where(a => a.Username.Contains(UserName)).ToList();   

        return PartialView("Userlist", U_master);
    }
```

By using this code i can search Username only Text box value will match with username of database table
but i want to display all the username record from database when user was the entered only single letter of Username ..and display all the Username who's name contain this letter .
please give format to write LIKE Query or give any example..!

Comment: what's your database? ms sql server, oracle or others?

Comment: @Michel jeams If the posts is useful for you ,then please mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use SqlMethods.Like(matchExpression,pattern)

```
var results = from c in db.costumers
              where SqlMethods.Like(c.FullName, "%"+FirstName+"%,"+LastName)
              select c;
```

The use of this method outside of LINQ to SQL will always throw a NotSupportedException exception.

**Source:** [Taken from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3913727/1073828)
*Also take a look at this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq)***