# SQL word wide "%like%" search in Entity Framework 6 using lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a SQL query shown below and I have to write an equivalent query in Entity Framework in C#. I have to make a join between to tables and I have to use SQL `LIKE` operator with each word in the search string. In the given example, the search string is "Life-Span Development 16E 99 Subject Index". I have been trying to write c# code for this but unable to achieve the expected result. Could you please help me to convert the SQL query to Entity framework equivalent query?

SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [titles].[title],
    [assets].[filename]
FROM 
    titles 
INNER JOIN 
    assets ON titles.ID = assets.ID 
WHERE 
    (title LIKE '%Life-Span%' 
     AND title LIKE '%Development%' 
     AND title LIKE '%16E%' 
     AND title LIKE '%99%' 
     AND title LIKE '%Subject%' 
     AND title LIKE '%Index%')
```

*C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string searchText = "Life-Span Development 16E 99 Subject Index";

    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        var result = db.titles
                    .Join(db.assets,
                            p => p.tid,
                            e => e.tid,
                            (p, e) => new {
                                 title = p.title1,
                                 fileName = e.filename
                            });               

        var searchTextArray = searchText.ToLower().Split(' ');
        result = result.Where(t => searchTextArray.Any(s => t.title.ToLower().Contains(s)));

        foreach(var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Title = {0} and finename = {1}", item.title, item.fileName));
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Does this compile?  It doesn't look like the foreach would work with var?

Comment: @AlexanderToptygin It compiles and runs.  For each works with var without any issue.

Comment: @Simant Does it work?  If not, how does it not work?

Comment: Well, how dynamic do you need to get?  Because as a base case you could always    db.SqlQuery("SELECT......").ToList();

Comment: @juharr The SQL query is correct and it gives me only one result in my result but the C# query gives me lots of records. My C# query doesn't give me a similar result as SQL query. Is there any alternate way to achieve this query in c#? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a LIKE query with linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913697/how-to-do-a-like-query-with-linq)

Comment: @Simant Have you tried .All(....) instead of .Any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the source of your problem:

```
result = result.Where(t => searchTextArray.Any(s => t.title.ToLower().Contains(s)));
```

`Any()` returns true if **one** match is found (or more, but it stops checking after one). It is the SQL equivalent of using `OR`.

What you want is this:

```
result = result.Where(t => searchTextArray.All(s => t.title.ToLower().Contains(s)));
```

`All()` returns true if **all** elements (in `searchTextArray`) have a match (in thise case, if all `searchTextArray` elements are contained in a given `title`). It is the SQL equivalent of using `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updated failure mode (too many results), change .Any to .All :

```
    result = result.Where(t => searchTextArray.All(s => t.title.ToLower().Contains(s)));
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit clunky but it does the job

```
namespace Like
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool Is(char a, char b)
        { 
              return a == b || 
              char.ToUpper(a) == b || 
              char.ToUpper(b) == a;
        }
        static bool IsLike(string sample, string query)
        {
            int k = 0;
            foreach (char c in sample)
            {
                if (!Is(c, query[k]))
                {
                    k = 0;
                    continue;
                }
                if (++k == query.Length)
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string testSample = "This is a str1ng 0f charac7er5";
            Console.WriteLine(IsLike(testSample, "this"));
            Console.WriteLine(IsLike(testSample, "of"));
            Console.WriteLine(IsLike(testSample, "chAra"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

yields
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE

Answer (score 0):

You may use [SqlMethods.Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx).

update your `searchText` variable as -

```
string searchText = "Life-Span%Development%16E%99%Subject%Index";
```

remove this code line -

```
var searchTextArray = searchText.ToLower().Split(' ');
```

then update the `Where` condition in `results` as

```
results = from r in results 
              where SqlMethods.Like(r.title,searchText )
              select r;
```

Comment: That is for LINQ to SQL and this query is for EF.